# PHPStorm сбивает форматирование устанавливая лишний таб

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains

При копи-пасте шторм ставит лишний таб. Как пофиксить?

Используемая версия PHPStorm 10.0.1, в 9 версии такого не было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: IDE выставляет для следующих строк такой же отступ что и у предыдущей? Если вы считаете, что это баг -- пишите в их техподдержку.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, порядок не важен. В техподдержку отпишусь, спасибо.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: это не баг, это настройка IDE. Можно и без техподдержки решить )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне помогло выключение `Indents detection`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]